# How to set ItemFlag in QTreeView or QListView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

**UPDATE1**:
QTreeView based on QFileSystemModel().

How to "setFlags" on specified tree item?

in a subclass QFileSystemModel()?

```py
class MyTreeModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
        # fake code:
        if current_index.parent() == treeView.rootIndex():
            # it is a second level folder.
            # set this tree item not selectable.
            current_index.setFlags(^ Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
```

Comment: What items and based on what? Can that flag change for any reason during runtime? Is the model static or does it layout change? The flags are always provided by the model (meaning [`flags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) must be reimplemented); if you want to be able to *programmatically* set flags for a specific index, you should keep internal references for each index and its customized flags (if any). That said, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to begin with, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I got inspiration from here:
[TreeView in Python+QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209771/treeview-in-pythonqt/21213768#21213768)

Similar to setData(), you cannot setData() to QFileSystemModel, but you can modify data() to add your code when reading data from the model.

You can't directly setFlags() to QFileSystemModel, but you can modify flags() to change the returned data.

```py
class MyTreeModel(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel):
    #...
    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(MyTreeModel, self).flags(index)
        # Determine directory level.
        if self.index_level(index) == 2:
            flags = flags ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        return flags
```